# display suite: limit field - determine what bundle values?

Tags: display-suite

In display suite, there's a field to limit which bundle it's being displayed on.

How do you know what bundle / value to enter?

Is there a way to list all available values or find out all the values? Or does it go by the machine name?

[image: Display Suite limit field]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the machine name. You can think of the bundle as the specific settings for a specific entity. So, DS is asking you for the machine name associated with the individual content type, vocabulary, etc. that you'd like to target.

For example, say you've created node configurations (Structure > Content Types) called "Article," "Store Location," and "Job Openings." If you'd like to make your DS custom code only available in the display settings for "Job Openings," you'd put in...

```
job_openings|*
```

...or you could limit it to a specific view mode by specifying which one in place of that wildcard, such as...

```
job_openings|teaser
```

Easiest way to find the machine name is to look at the edit url for your entity and/or view mode.

Answer (score 0):

The following is hard to find: If you need to limit the field to a DS view you need to use the following syntax on the "Limit field" field in the field configuration:

```
products-page|default
```

Where "products" is the name of the view and "page" is the display name.